# React Native Logging in to Web Page

Tags: react-native, mobile-development

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I could go about writing a piece of code for react native that takes an input from the user (username and password) and then logins into a website with in.

Also any react native web scraping libraries anyone could recommend (I was thinking about using Cheerio)

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For getting user inputtext check:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_text_input.htm

From now on what i'm saying works in restful APIs and you may need to change your approach based on your need.

In my case being logged in means having a valid token from server.

For sending requests use `axios`. Get your user input values and make a post request to login api. If credentials were valid response will contain a  token. Save that token in your app using Asyncstorage.

For logging out delete that token from storage.